# Powershell - Time Duration Between Hashtable Objects

Tags: powershell, loops, time, hashtable, duration

I am trying to create a time duration between objects in a hashtable. So, i am pulling the eventlogs to show when the machine was locked and unlocked:

```
$Unlocks = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName = 'Security'; ID = '4801' }
$Locks = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName = 'Security'; ID = '4800' }
$AllEvents = $Unlocks + $Locks
$OrderedEvents = $AllEvents | Sort-Object TimeCreated
```

This gives me this output:

```
TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
24/07/2020 07:41:06           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…
24/07/2020 07:42:27           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.…
24/07/2020 07:58:56           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…
24/07/2020 07:59:13           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.…
24/07/2020 09:36:01           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…
24/07/2020 09:41:50           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.…
24/07/2020 10:30:42           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…
24/07/2020 10:31:25           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.…
24/07/2020 12:22:51           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…
24/07/2020 12:35:55           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.…
24/07/2020 13:16:07           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…
24/07/2020 13:27:28           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.…
```

So i would like to add the duration between the events.

For example,

```
TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message  Duration
-----------                     -- ---------------- ------- --------
24/07/2020 07:41:06           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.…   
24/07/2020 07:42:27           4801 Information      The workstation was unlocked.… 1min 21sec
24/07/2020 07:58:56           4800 Information      The workstation was locked.… 16min 29sec
```

Obviously the first entry would not have a time. The duration is looking at the previous entry. The format of the time isnt important as i will convert it later.

When i search for ways to resolve this, the results dont quite do what i need, but i am sure this is probably me not using the right words.

I tried this, but it didnt provide what i wanted, nor did i properly understand it:

```
$OrderedEvents | ForEach-Object { $_.TimeCreated = [datetime]$_.TimeCreated; $_ } | 
Group-Object  Id |
ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Sort-Object TimeCreated  }
```

That just provided me the two latest entries.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks
POC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of addressing this problem. The primary piece your missing is a variable to hold the previous entry.

```
$last = $null
$OrderedEvents | ForEach-Object { 
    $duration = [timespan]0
    $timeStamp = [datetime]$_.TimeCreated
    if ($null -ne $last) {
        $duration = $last - $timeStamp
    }
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Duration -Value $duration -PassThru
    $last = $timeStamp
} | Select-Object -Property Duration, TimeCreated, Id, LevelDisplayName, Message
```

I added a `$last` variable to hold the timestamp from the previous entry. I also used Add-Member to add a new `Duration` property to the existing object. `Duration` will be a `[Timespan]` object which will likely look something like `00:05:00.0046918` when written to the console. If you want more human-readable values, you could use [PowerShellHumanizer](https://github.com/dfinke/PowerShellHumanizer) by changing `$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Duration -Value $duration -PassThru` to `$_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Duration -Value $duration.Humanize() -PassThru` which would change Duration to a string like "5 minutes, 4 milliseconds".

Comment: Thanks, this was the approach i was thinking i was going to need to take.

Thanks for such a quick reply too!